Enumerate emoji sequences supported by a font typeface
How can I determine which Unicode multi code-point Emoji ZWJ Sequences a particular TTF or OTF font supports?
WPF can enumerate all the single code-points a font supports via GlyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap:
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Emoji");
fontFamily.GetTypefaces()
    .First()
    .TryGetGlyphTypeface(out var glyphTypeface);

IDictionary<int, ushort> characterMap = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap;

To test if a particular Emoji Sequence is supported I've tried...
String.EnumerateRunes(), but it returns the number of code-points in the sequence.
StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator() is not font aware - it returns the expected number elements - even if the font falls-back to the component parts of the sequence.
private int CountTextElements(string text)
{
    TextElementEnumerator myTEE = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(text);
    int count = 0;
    while (myTEE.MoveNext()) { count++; }
    return count;
}

//1F469 200D 1F52C; RGI_Emoji_ZWJ_Sequence; woman scientist # E4.0   [1] (‍)
string sci = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F469)  // U+1F469 : WOMAN
           + char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x200D)   // U+0200D : ZERO WIDTH JOINER [ZWJ]
           + char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F52C); // U+1F52C : MICROSCOPE

int runeCount = sci.EnumerateRunes().Count();  // returns 3
int textElementCount = CountTextElements(sci); // returns 1

// This emoji sequence is new to Unicode 15.1 and is not supported by many fonts yet
//     so on display it falls back to it's visible parts  & ➡️
//1F6B6 200D 27A1 FE0F; RGI_Emoji_ZWJ_Sequence; person walking facing right # E15.1  [1] (‍➡️)
string wlk = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F6B6) // U+1F6B6 : PEDESTRIAN {walking}
           + char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x200D)  // U+0200D : ZERO WIDTH JOINER [ZWJ]
           + char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x27A1)  // U+027A1 : BLACK RIGHTWARDS ARROW
           + char.ConvertFromUtf32(0xFE0F); // U+0FE0F : VARIATION SELECTOR-16 [VS16] {emoji variation selector}
       
runeCount = wlk.EnumerateRunes().Count();  // returns 4
textElementCount = CountTextElements(wlk); // returns 1

So how can I tell if an Emoji sequence will display correctly as a single unit or will fall back to it's component parts?
NB: Ideally I would like to establish supported Emoji sequences from the font file itself (similar to CharacterToGlyphMap) rather than try and create/render/test each sequence as I've tried above.

Emoji zwj sequences would have to be supported in a font's GSUB table, and there's no .Net API that exposes that data directly. You'd need to use GlyphTypeface.GetFontStream to access the binary font data and parse that table looking for type 4 lookup tables. But it's probably easier to try drawing each sequence and see whether a single glyph (not glyph ID 0) is returned.

Damn - that GSUB stuff is quite... esoteric.
What do you mean by draw? Perhaps SkiaSharp.HarfBuzz?

By "draw", I really mean anything that results in deriving the final glyph sequence. If you're using SkiaSharp, then SKShaper.Result would work. Shaping will process the GSUB glyphs substitution actions. If you shape an emoji zwj sequence and end up with a single glyph ID that's not glyph ID 0, then that would be an emoji glyph for that sequence. If you end up with same number of glyph IDs as the Unicode characters (excluding ZWJ) in the emoji ZWJ sequence, then that sequence isn't supported in the font as a combined emoji.

Thanks Peter. Length of SKShaper.Result.Clusters does the trick.

SkiaSharp.HarfBuzz shapes text as defined in font typefaces, and can be used to test how many "clusters" are in a string.
If a font supports an emoji sequence, SKShaper.Shape() will return a single cluster, otherwise it will return a cluster for each code-point in the sequence (excluding U+0200D : ZERO WIDTH JOINER).
Here is an example:
private int ClusterCount(string text, string fontFilePath)
{
    using SKTypeface sKTypeface = SKTypeface.FromFile(fontFilePath);
    using SKShaper sKShaper = new SKShaper(sKTypeface);
    using SKPaint paint = new SKPaint();
    SKShaper.Result result = sKShaper.Shape(text, paint);
    return result.Clusters.Length;
}

private void SKShaperTest()
{
    // This emoji sequence is new to Unicode 15.1 and is not supported by many fonts yet
    //     so on display it falls back to it's visible parts  & ➡️
    //1F6B6 200D 27A1 FE0F; RGI_Emoji_ZWJ_Sequence; person walking facing right # E15.1  [1] (‍➡️)
    string wlk = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F6B6) // U+1F6B6 : PEDESTRIAN {walking}
                + char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x200D)  // U+0200D : ZERO WIDTH JOINER [ZWJ]
                + char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x27A1)  // U+027A1 : BLACK RIGHTWARDS ARROW
                + char.ConvertFromUtf32(0xFE0F); // U+0FE0F : VARIATION SELECTOR-16 [VS16] {emoji variation selector}

    // Segoe UI Emoji
    int font1count = ClusterCount(wlk, @"seguiemj.ttf");       // ClusterCount returns 3

    // Noto Color Emoji
    int font2count = ClusterCount(wlk, @"NotoColorEmoji.ttf"); // ClusterCount returns 1
}

A good list of emoji sequences for testing can be found by parsing emoji-test.txt on the official unicode.org website.
NB: The SKShaper.Result.Codepoints returned are not the code points from the input emoji sequence (they appear to be the glyph indices as defined by the font 'CMAP' table).
